# Header Row in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need on this query something to group the rows only by CLIENTI.BRAND (customer name/brand). This is a table from a CRM and it contains customers referents names and information and a contact register.

I need something that just displays the rows in this way:

| BRAND |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BRAND | SITO | NOMINATIVO | EMAIL | TELEFONO | CATEGORIA | DATA_CONTATTO.... |
| BRAND | SITO | NOMINATIVO | EMAIL | TELEFONO | CATEGORIA | DATA_CONTATTO.... |
| **BRAND** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| BRAND | SITO | NOMINATIVO | EMAIL | TELEFONO | CATEGORIA | DATA_CONTATTO.... |
| BRAND | SITO | NOMINATIVO | EMAIL | TELEFONO | CATEGORIA | DATA_CONTATTO.... |

Here is the query

```
SELECT 
    CLIENTI.ID, CLIENTI.BRAND, CLIENTI.SITO, 
    CONTATTI.NOMINATIVO, CONTATTI.EMAIL, CONTATTI.TELEFONO, 
    CATEGORIE.CATEGORIA,
    REGISTRO.[DATA CONTATTO] AS DATA_CONTATTO,
    REGISTRO.AGENZIE, REGISTRO.[NOTE INVIO] AS NOTE_INVIO,
    REGISTRO.[INVIATO DA] AS INVIATO_DA, CLIENTI.STATO,
    REGISTRO.TIPO_CONTATTO AS [Tipo Contatto],
    REGISTRO.[RICONTATTARE], Registro.Data_Ricontattare,
    CLIENTI.DataInserimento
FROM 
    (((CLIENTI
LEFT JOIN 
    CONTATTI ON CLIENTI.ID = CONTATTI.AZIENDA)
LEFT JOIN 
    CATEGORIE ON CLIENTI.CATEGORIA = CATEGORIE.ID)
LEFT JOIN 
    REGISTRO ON CLIENTI.ID = REGISTRO.CLIENTE)
WHERE 
    BLACKLIST = FALSE
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the question? You should replace that BLACKLIST = FALSE with BLACKLIST = 0 (it is a bit field, right?)

Comment: You want to use a **bold** data type for the first result column so that every third result row is **BRAND** without additional column values? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Is not bold or blacklist = 0...it's just displaying one row with the brand and the detail of it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try following Code:**

```
declare @TableTemp table
(
ID int , BRAND nvarchar(50), SITO nvarchar(50), 
NOMINATIVO nvarchar(50), EMAIL nvarchar(50), TELEFONO nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @TableTemp (ID , BRAND    ,   SITO   ,    NOMINATIVO  , EMAIL      , TELEFONO)
                values (1  , N'Brand1',  N'Sito1',  N'NOMINATIVO1', N'a@f.com' , N'+1454')
insert into @TableTemp (ID , BRAND    ,   SITO   ,    NOMINATIVO  , EMAIL      , TELEFONO)
                values (2  , N'Brand1',  N'Sito2',  N'NOMINATIVO2', N'ee@f.com' , N'+1754')
insert into @TableTemp (ID , BRAND    ,   SITO   ,    NOMINATIVO  , EMAIL      , TELEFONO)
                values (3  , N'Brand2',  N'Sito3',  N'NOMINATIVO3', N'a5@f.com' , N'+1434')
insert into @TableTemp (ID , BRAND    ,   SITO   ,    NOMINATIVO  , EMAIL      , TELEFONO)
                values (4  , N'Brand2',  N'Sito4',  N'NOMINATIVO3', N'e8@f.com' , N'+1954')
insert into @TableTemp (ID , BRAND    ,   SITO   ,    NOMINATIVO  , EMAIL      , TELEFONO)
                values (5  , N'Brand1',  N'Sito2',  N'NOMINATIVO2', N'ee@f.com' , N'+1754')

insert into @TableTemp (ID ,  BRAND , SITO,NOMINATIVO , EMAIL , TELEFONO)
select distinct         null, BRAND , null, null      , null  , null     from @TableTemp

SELECT   BRAND , SITO,NOMINATIVO , EMAIL , TELEFONO FROM @TableTemp
ORDER BY BRAND , ID
```

**After Running SQL Code: (Result)**

```
|BRAND |SITO |  NOMINATIVO| EMAIL|  TELEFONO|
|:-----|:---:|:----------:|:--------:| --------:|
|Brand1|     |            |          |          |
|Brand1|Sito1|NOMINATIVO1 |a@f.com   |  +1454   |
|Brand1|Sito2|NOMINATIVO2 |ee@f.com  |  +1754   |
|Brand1|Sito2|NOMINATIVO2 |ee@f.com  |  +1754   |
|Brand2|     |            |          |          |
|Brand2|Sito3|NOMINATIVO3 |a5@f.com  |  +1434   |
|Brand2|Sito4|NOMINATIVO3 |e8@f.com  |  +1954   |
```

[image: Result]